# Import all imports from another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Is it possible to have a JS file import all the imports from another js file? I want to have a set of imports for my react app that only import when the app is in dev mode and I want to store these imports in a dev-config.js file, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The export parameters specify individual named exports, while the import * as name syntax imports all of them. Below are examples to clarify the syntax.

```
import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Here, accessing the exports means using the module name ("myModule" in this case) as a namespace. For example, if the module imported above includes an export doAllTheAmazingThings(), you would call it like this:

```
myModule.doAllTheAmazingThings();
```